# Верна ли пунктуация вкупе с кавычками?

Tags: пунктуация

> И нужно уметь придать линии поведения героя целостность, что
>   называется, обнаружить «сквозное действие», «сверхзадачу», а ещё знать
>   точно: «что я хочу», «чего добиваюсь» – в любой из моментов
>   сценического времени.

Смотрится неплохо, а там кто его знает... Мы университетов не кончали (с).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне кажется, с запятыми (сложноподчинённое предл.) было бы вернее:

*И нужно уметь придать линии поведения героя целостность, что называется, 
обнаружить «сквозное действие», «сверхзадачу», а ещё знать точно, «что я хочу», «чего добиваюсь» в любой из моментов сценического времени.*

Или тире было поставлено, чтобы указать, что "в любой из моментов сценического времени" относится к "знать точно", а не к "чего добиваюсь"?

Comment: Смысл по-другому: *В любой из моментов сценического времени <необходимо> знать точно: «что я хочу», «чего добиваюсь».*

Comment: Если "В любой из моментов сценического времени  необходимо  знать точно", то вместо тире запятая.